# Changing images dynamically from a Sprite?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, haxe

I have been looking for this answer for days now and no matter how much I look I can't find it for the life of me.

I understand that you can change a bitmap's image easily with something like this:

var image = new Bitmap (Assets.getBitmapData ("image.png"));

// (and later)

image.bitmapData = Assets.getBitmapData ("another-image.png");

but bitmap doesn't support mouse events. Let's say I want to change an image when someone clicks on it, thus I need it to be a sprite. Is there an easy way to just change the image of a sprite? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You can do it one of two ways.

1. You create a custom class for this and add the bitmap as a public property
2. You add the bitmap to the Sprite and access it through there. See:

.

```
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
this.addChild( this.container );
this.container.addChild( this.bitmap );

// to change the bitmap
this.bitmap.bitmapData = new BitmapData();

// or 
var bmp:Bitmap = this.container.getChildAt( 0 ) as Bitmap;
bmp.bitmapData = new BitmapData();
```

The second option assumes the bitmap is the *only* object in the sprite. If you add more objects to the sprite, you may have to tweak the index accordingly.

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much I managed to finally do it. Although I'm pretty disappointed that I have to create 2 variables for this to work =( Anyway, thanks a lot!